# How do i fix the position of NerdTree in while opening files

Tags: vim

i'm using the gvim and have NerdTree installed. When gvim is opend NerdTree is coming on left side (this is is where i want it, while opening files ).
When a file is being opened using the NerdTree, NT position is changed and coming on right side in split window

i want it to stay on left side (as it was at start) while opening files from it.

Comment: What key do you use for opening files? Just `o` or enter should open it on the right. What you describe is what the `s` (for splitting) does for me.

Comment: using <enter> ,tried o and s

Comment: Could you try `:set splitbelow splitright`?